# Is it possible to know workflow expected input arguments in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, workflow-services

I'm developing a windows workflow application that use a lot of workflows each one is in a separate dll and they are loaded dynamically at application startup.

All workflows share a common list of possible input arguments (It is not mandatory for workflow to take all possible arguments)

my question is. Is it possible that when i load a workflow and before starting it to know expected input arguments? as you know if i send an unexpected argument an exception will occurred?

Comment: Not sure about that. But how about using param or optional arguments in your function?

Comment: Thank you for reply, It is not a function it is workflow input arguments, and yes i can use a dictionary or array of objects as input but i can't know which inputs are required as i'm not controlling workflow development and if i sent all possible inputs then workflow developers should perform casting from object type to required type (Inputs are not from same type) and this required some code in workflow (and maybe adding some activities) which i'm trying to avoid, i'm trying to simplify workflows development. Actually there are multiple reasons why i don't want to use an array or dictionary.